# Why does the chat has to be so aggressive at banning you?

Tags: discussion, support

(Seth and the mods already know about this, moderators do not post)

So today I was talking blah blah blah where the point that I was suspended for 60 mins for **NO REASON**. then I wasted 60 min. of my life waiting to see if i can chat again.

And i know what you guys are thinking "this can't go any worse" **Well it did.**

I was on the AskUbuntu chat and more chatter chatter and I got banned for **30 mins.** Then the other mod was having a little laugh session saying "heh, that's what I thought"

If we combine that ban time (30+60) it means I have been suspended for around 90 mins.

**Now mods, you might take this as a complaint and close this and ban my account from SE but hear me out.**

Why can't we have a little laugh session in the chat than "suspending" people for having a little fun? Why does it have to be like **hell?**

Why, just why? Now I regret going on the chat now because if I do, I will get suspended again.

Admins and mods, please fix this problem.

(UPDATE: ok guys, you win. i have just moved to super user so hope to see you there)

Comment: I do not think it is appropriate to name drop a specific admin/mod/owner/whatever when other users have expressed disinterest in your contributions to chat. Or even the feeling that chat is being spammed.

Comment: If you don't want to talk about it, then why post on meta?

Comment: I down voted because you are not taking into account your behavior from another perspective. I believe you said you created this account because I muted your previous one. If that IS the case, then you need to realize that your comments did not contribute well to the discussion. Saying random words just to beat a record, or things that users don't approve of, is not helpful.

Comment: Well, this IS tagged as "discussion", and I am explaining my views since you are visiting chat only to say goodbye, a second time now. Now, I know that no one in chat is trying to kick you out, but when showing childish (telling us goodbye forever because you had a down vote) or otherwise inappropriate/annoying behavior, something needs to be done. And, instead of trying to come to a solution or agreeing to stop spamming, you instead complained adamantly in chat about being banned temp.

Comment: Note: downvotes on meta indicate disagreement.

Comment: @Edity, one last comment from me -- I pinged you in Ubuntu chat a couple times, hoping you could come back and try to be a team player. No one wants you to feel like you do, but you need to understand (see chat)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Moderators have a difficult responsibility: to balance each member's right to speak their mind with the need to maintain order. Most of the time, this is an easy task. However, there are times when a moderator needs to intervene in order to prevent problems from escalating further.

Without getting too specific, you were [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29800643#29800643) a number of times to stop repeatedly posting things, and failed to do so. Although we allow non-Ubuntu-related discussion in chat, there is an expectation that conversations should not inhibit discussion of the room's primary topic. Your messages crossed that line. Just because you're having fun, that doesn't mean everyone else is.

I would also like to point out that 90 minutes is not a long period of time.

Answer (score 26):

I'm not a moderator on Ask Ubuntu, but I am a moderator over on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/). I'm also the moderator that suspended you for an hour earlier today.

I suspended you because of your behavior in the [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) chat room. In the past 48 hours, in that room alone, you've been asked repeatedly by network moderators, room owners and room regulars to keep the conversation on topic. Instead, you've spammed the room and ignored everyone so that you could get privileges to Smoke Detector. You then lost that access within hours for further bad behavior and returned to spamming the room.

Chat rooms are not your personal playground. Stack Exchange is definitely not where you should be posting stuff like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE8t8.png) or telling others what racist terms mean. Quiet frankly, you needed a time out. I gave you one for an hour. I also mentioned that

> [[Y]ou've been asked by multiple users to respect the room topic and you have not. When you return, do so](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29798749#29798749)

I'm sorry to say that based on your more recent behavior, you didn't follow that bit of advice.

---

The point of the suspension is to help you realize that something needs to change. Look at everything you've been told. Look at your behavior, the advice you've been provided and the answers to this question. That type of behavior needs to stop. Now.